# How to define three table relationship in models in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

In my project there are three table like (teacher, attendance,user) and i have define the relationship in there model. in teacher table relation with both attendance and user but user has no relationship with attendance when i want to fetch data it show an error like `Property [attendance_status] does not exist on this collection instance`. how can i solve this problems.

This is User model

```
public function teacher() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Teacher');
}
```

this is Teacher model

```
public function attendance() {
    return $this->hasMany(Attendance::class,'teacher_id','user_id');
}
```

this is attendance model

```
public function teacher() {
   return $this->belongsTo(Teacher::class,'teacher_id','user_id');
}
```

and in my attendance controller I define like this

```
$staffAttendances = Teacher::with(['attendance','user'])->get();

foreach ($staffAttendances as $attd) {          
      echo $attd->user->first_name .'<br>';
      echo $attd->designation.'<br>';
      echo $attd->attendance->attendance_status.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: does your attendance table have an attendance_status field? Also, you should check first $atted->attendance is populated, if the staff doesn't have an attendance to begin with, you have no attendance_status to retrieve.

Comment: yes in my attendances table attendance_status is exist if i do this $atted->attendance all data is fetching but i need only attendance_status field

Comment: $attd->attendance show all the data like [{"id":1,"attendance_status":"Present","date_time":"2018-09-14 00:00:00","latitude":"2342332","longitude":"346534","reason":"Yes","teacher_id":5,"school_id":1,"created_at":"2018-09-14 06:52:56","updated_at":"2018-09-14 06:52:56"}]

Comment: @shahid From the data output, it looks like an array. Try `$attd->attendance[0]['attendance_status']`

Comment: if i do  this $attd->attendance[0]['attendance_status'] it shows the error like Undefined offset: 0

Comment: @shahid and does all staff contain attendance?

Comment: yes all staff can mark attendance

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $attd->attendance[0]->attendance_status
```